# adding a partition drive, which drive to manage?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I wish to partition my Windows C drive. I'm at the level of where I can reasonably follow instructions (which are well referenced on the internet). However, when I open disk management I see there are two drives "OS (C:)" and something labelled "Healthy (Primary Partition)" (see attached image). Which drive to I take space from?[image]

Comment: You should determine what’s with the extra partitions on “Disk 0”. Did you have Linux installed?

Comment: @DanielB I have installed Linux Mint so that my machine is dual boot. Is this the origin of the partition called "Healthy (Primary Partition)"? I wish to create a separate partion on the Windows 10 part of the machine.

Comment: If you wish to partition Windows C drive then partition OS (C:). I assume all other partitions are for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to partition Windows C drive then partition

> OS (C:)

The others you can leave as they are probably the various partitions made by Linux.
.